# trying to use CPAN with my MINGW version for Git Bash

Tags: mingw, cpan

I am trying to use use cpan on my windows install version of Git Bash `git version 2.18.0.windows.1`.  I installed an Active Perl version `version 24, subversion 3 (v5.24.3) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread`  and it is located in `C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe`.  I can run `cpan` in the cmd under windows just fine but I cannot seem to get it to run in git bash because of the perl5 that comes with it.  I either get this error:

`Can't locate CPAN/Author.pm in @INC (you may need to install the CPAN::Author module) (@INC contains: /c/Perl64/site/bin /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl) at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/CPAN.pm line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/CPAN.pm line 19.
Compilation failed in require at /c/Octave/Octave-4.4.1/bin/cpan line 119.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /c/Octave/Octave-4.4.1/bin/cpan line 119.`

Or when I add the folder than holds the `CPAN` folder and consequently `Perl` folder to the `@INC` path with `export PERL5LIB=/c/Perl64/lib` I get this error:

`Cwd.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0000000600000570, needed 0000000000000000)`

Here is print out of @INC path after addition:

`~$ perl -e "print qq(@INC)"
/c/Perl64/lib /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl~$`

How can I make sure git bash runs cpan like it does in windows?

The full paths that were added when I installed ActivePerl are `C:\Perl64\bin` which holds the `lib` folder which holds the `CPAN` folder (and in it the `Author.pm` file) and `C:\Perl64\site\bin` and cpan runs fine in windows cmd.

I am ultimately trying to configure and install packages all my self learning for git bash and got to these problems because when I try to configure I get this issue.  Been at it for 16 of last 24 hours:

`intltool-0.51.0$ ./configure --prefix=/mingw`

`checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for perl >= 5.8.1... 5.26.2
checking for XML::Parser... configure: error: XML::Parser perl module is required for intltool`

Comment: You will need to set up `$PATH` under bash so that `/cygdrive/C/Perl64/bin` comes before `/bin/` (or wherever the Git `perl` lives). This might screw up `git` or other of its tools for you, so proceed with caution.

Comment: so I added it first and `which perl` points to that one now but when i enter `cpan` i still get the first error `Can't locate CPAN/Author.pm in @INC (you may need to install the CPAN::Author module)`  it keeps trying to run `/usr/share/perl5/core_perl/CPAN.pm line 19` from the git perl

Comment: You will also need to add the directory where the correct `cpan.bat` sits to the front of `$PATH`. Maybe that's `/cygdrive/C/Perl64/perl/bin` or something. This is mostly a shell question and not a Perl question.

Comment: thanks,  i will try that, i was able to run the configure file without it however now when running `make` i get this error `make: /bin/sh: Command not found make: *** [Makefile:460: all-recursive] Error 127`.  i should probably create a new question cause i cannot find answer

Comment: You still got programs from the `perl` distributed with `git` in your path before the programs from the `perl` you want to use. You will really need to clean up your $PATH variable, or maybe settle on not using Cygwin.

Comment: yes thanks, it seems that you will always run into issues if you use cygwin and git, lot of resources say you cannot do it,  i just updated my git for the new packages, thanks!

Comment: @BrianWiley, so the solution for this was...?  I tried to put `/usr/bin/vendor_perl` and `/usr/bin/core_perl` at the beginning of the path and its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can install perl natively on windows, then *alias* your gitbash to that perl. In my case, I've install perl to `C:\Perl64`, then I add to my `~/.bashrc`

```
alias perl=/c/Perl64/bin/perl.exe
```

GitBash will then use the perl you've installed instead of the perl delivered with git.

Comment: I tried that, but it did not work. Its still using the perl from /usr/bin. I have the original perl also in PATH, and 'where perl' showes me both locations. I renamed the git-bash-perl then git-bash decided to use the other perl.